# How to cut html tags on JSP page

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I need to cut html tags in JSP view on client side.

I have something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${myitemsList}" var="temp">
   ... 
   <p class="myClass"> 
     ${temp}
   </p>
   ...
</c:forEach>
```

Inside every `${temp}` there is some html code like `<p>Some text <span>example</span></p>`. I need to cut this html tags to have pure text: `Some text example`.

Of course I could just add model object without html tags but I need to do cut this on client side. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  On the client side, you have only HTML/JavaScript (not JSP) - once you have the rendered HTML tags, you could use JS to add/remove/hide DOM elements (tags) - is that what you mean? handling the DOM using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but using js is working on client site, thats exactly what I mean ;) I need a way to cut this html on client site, no matter how (js or any other way)